# Jquery/javascript function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, jquery-selectors

I have a javascript function doing some animation and its parameter is a parent selector.

```
function myFunction(a)
{
$("'"+a+">#one'").stop(true, true).animate({left:'30px'},1100);
$("'"+a+">#two'").stop(true, true).animate({left:'30px'},1100);
}
```

and the following line is calling that function.

```
$("#main").mouseleave(myFunction("#main"));
```

but this is not working, can anyone tell me whats wrong in my code ?

Comment: Well, what does it do? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/ifunof/1/edit

```
function myFunction(a){
    $(a+">#one").stop().animate({left:30},1100); // <-- fixed selectors
    $(a+">#two").stop().animate({left:30},1100);
}

$("#main").mouseleave(function(){ // <-- (immediate call: Wrong)
  myFunction("#main");            // <-- fn reference: OK!
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of issues there:

### 1. Selectors

Just do the string substitution in your head. If you're passing `#main` into your function, then your selectors end up looking like this:

```
$("'#main>#one'")...
```

Note the `'` characters in there. Now, if you remove the `'` characters, you'll get:

```
$("#main>#one")...
```

...which means "the element with the `id` `"one"` that's a child of the element with the `id` `"main"`. That now works, but it suggests you're using the same `id` (`"one"`) for more than one element. You **cannot** do that in HTML.

Your `id="one"` and `id="two"` elements should probably have `class="one"` and `class="two"` instead, and if so your code should look like this:

```
function myFunction(a)
{
$(a+">.one").stop(true, true).animate({left:'30px'},1100);
$(a+">.two").stop(true, true).animate({left:'30px'},1100);
}
```

### 2. Functions

In your code *calling* `myFunction`:

```
$("#main").mouseleave(myFunction("#main")); // <== Wrong
```

...you're calling `myFunction` **immediately** and passing its return value into `mouseleave`. Since it has no explicit return value, you end up assing `undefined` into `mouseleave`, which won't do anything useful.

If your goal is to have `myFunction` **called** when the `mouseleave` event occurs, you pass in a function reference:

```
$("#main").mouseleave(function() {
    myFunction("#main");
});
```

It may be worth stepping back from your current task and working through a few basic jQuery (and JavaScript) tutorials, to cement your understanding some of these concepts like `id`s being unique, passing functions as event handlers, string concatenation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The selector is being concatenated incorrectly.  The jquery function takes a String for the selector argument, there is no need to wrap it in single quotes.

```
function myFunction(a)
{
    $(a+">#one").stop(true, true).animate({left:'30px'},1100);
    $(a+">#two").stop(true, true).animate({left:'30px'},1100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`mouseLeave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) function takes a function as a parameter. You're passing in an executed function (one with parameters) so the result of your function is being passed as the parameter to `mouseLeave` (rather than the function itself).

You need to wrap it another function that would call your `myFunction` function in a new anonymous function.

Assuming the `myFunction` piece is correct then you need something like this:

```
$("#main").mouseleave(new function() {
    myFunction("#main");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$(a+" > #one").stop(true, true).animate({left:'30px'},1100);
$(a+" > #two").stop(true, true).animate({left:'30px'},1100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two things wrong in your code:

- Your selector becomes `"'#main>#one'"`. This will not select anything. You probably want to omit the apostrophes:

  ```
  $(a+" > #one")…
  ```

  But since ids are unique in a document, you won't need the `#main` prefix anyway. Just use the ids directly:

  ```
  $("#one, #two").stop(true, true).animate({left:'30px'},1100);
  ```
- You are [calling the function directly](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html#link2) (and passing its result, `undefined`, to the `mouseleave` method), instead of adding it as an event handler. Instead, use

  ```
  $("#main").mouseleave(function(e) {
       myFunction("#main");
  });
  ```